# Is there an up-to-date "Blog this in windows live writer" in any of the modern browsers?

Tags: blogging, windows-live-writer

I want to select text (and images) in the browser, right click, and have it added to my blog post draft in windows live writer? 
The one I could find seems to be for old versions of Firefox (10 versions behind).

Comment: Actually, with the new (too fast!) Firefox version numbering system, 10 versions behind means just 5-6 months old. Probably it could still work - did you try?

Comment: I downloaded this a while ago - http://plugins.live.com/writer/detail/blog-this-for-firefox 
but firefox does not seem to know how to use it/install it

Comment: Does [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scribefire-next/) work?

Comment: scribe fire (from previous link) is a different tool, I was hoping to stick to windows live writer.